# 415 Unsupported Media Type: Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'

Tags: json, http

I get the error:

> Error: 415 Unsupported Media Type: Did not attempt to load JSON data
> because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'.

when trying to send a request from the frontend. What could be the problem? At the same time, the data is correctly saved in the database. When I use the same request in Postman, I get an HTML page in response (maybe that’s the problem?)

I use:

> Flask-WTF==0.15.1 Flask==2.1.2 Flask-MongoEngine==1.0.0
> Werkzeug==2.3.0 Flask-Cors Flask-Socketio

Frontend code:

```
document.getElementById('createRequestModal').querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    const dateInput = document.getElementById('input-date');
    const hoursContainer = document.getElementById('hours-container');
    const hourRows = hoursContainer.getElementsByClassName('hour-template');
    const hoursData = [];

    for (const hourRow of hourRows) {
        const hourValue = hourRow.querySelector('.hour-value').textContent;
        const energyInput = hourRow.querySelector('.energy-input');
        const energyValue = energyInput.value.trim();

        if (energyValue !== '') {
            hoursData.push({
                hour: hourValue,
                energy: energyValue
            });
        }
    }

    const formData = {
        date: dateInput.value,
        hours: hoursData
    };

    fetch('/create_request', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
});
```

Server code:

```
@app.route('/create_request', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def create_request():
    try:
        data = request.get_json()
        print(request.json)
        print(request.get_json())
        print(data)

        date_str = data.get('date')
        hours_data = data.get('hours', [])

        date = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')

        new_request = Request(user=current_user, user_type=current_user.user_type, date=date, hours=[])

        for hour_entry in hours_data:
            hour_value = hour_entry.get('hour', '').split(' ')[1]
            energy = hour_entry.get('energy', '')
            new_hour = Hour(hour_value=hour_value, energy=energy)
            new_request.hours.append(new_hour)

        new_request.save()
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard', user_type=current_user.user_type))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", str(e))
        return jsonify({'message': 'error'})
```

Frontend logs (JSON.stringify(formData)):

> {   "date": "2023-11-01",   "hours": [
> {
> "hour": "Час 00:00",
> "energy": "100"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 01:00",
> "energy": "150"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 02:00",
> "energy": "120"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 03:00",
> "energy": "200"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 04:00",
> "energy": "100"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 05:00",
> "energy": "150"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 06:00",
> "energy": "120"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 07:00",
> "energy": "200"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 08:00",
> "energy": "100"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 09:00",
> "energy": "150"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 10:00",
> "energy": "120"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 11:00",
> "energy": "200"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 12:00",
> "energy": "100"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 13:00",
> "energy": "150"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 14:00",
> "energy": "120"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 15:00",
> "energy": "200"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 16:00",
> "energy": "100"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 17:00",
> "energy": "150"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 18:00",
> "energy": "120"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 19:00",
> "energy": "200"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 20:00",
> "energy": "100"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 21:00",
> "energy": "150"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 22:00",
> "energy": "120"
> },
> {
> "hour": "Час 23:00",
> "energy": "200"
> }   ] }

Server logs (request.get_json()):

> {'date': '2023-11-01', 'hours': [{'hour': 'Час 00:00', 'energy':
> '100'}, {'hour': 'Час 01:00', 'energy': '150'}, {'hour': 'Час 02:00',
> 'energy': '120'}, {'hour': 'Час 03:00', 'energy': '200'}, {'hour':
> 'Час 04:00', 'energy': '100'}, {'hour': 'Час 05:00', 'energy': '150'},
> {'hour': 'Час 06:00', 'energy': '120'}, {'hour': 'Час 07:00',
> 'energy': '200'}, {'hour': 'Час 08:00', 'energy': '100'}, {'hour':
> 'Час 09:00', 'energy': '150'}, {'hour': 'Час 10:00', 'energy': '120'},
> {'hour': 'Час 11:00', 'energy': '200'}, {'hour': 'Час 12:00',
> 'energy': '100'}, {'hour': 'Час 13:00', 'energy': '150'}, {'hour':
> 'Час 14:00', 'energy': '120'}, {'hour': 'Час 15:00', 'energy': '200'},
> {'hour': 'Час 16:00', 'energy': '100'}, {'hour': 'Час 17:00',
> 'energy': '150'}, {'hour': 'Час 18:00', 'energy': '120'}, {'hour':
> 'Час 19:00', 'energy': '200'}, {'hour': 'Час 20:00', 'energy': '100'},
> {'hour': 'Час 21:00', 'energy': '150'}, {'hour': 'Час 22:00',
> 'energy': '120'}, {'hour': 'Час 23:00', 'energy': '200'}]}

Comment: were you able to figure out a solution ? I have same issue happening in my project